# OSB - sending request to many endpoints

Tags: endpoint, osb

I need to know if using Oracle Service Bus 11g I can send request to more then one endpoint at the same time. I really would like how to do it.

regards, 
Arek

Answer (score 0):

To send request to more then one endpoint, please configure different Business Services for the endpoints & you can use multiple Service Callouts to send the requests to these Business Services.

Thanks,
Yogesh